# I can't edit a message in another text channel

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to edit an embed message sent by my bot (today) using this code:

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
if (!args.length) {
    return message.channel.send('Non hai specificato il messaggio!');
}

const nuovoMsg = args.slice(3).join(' ');
const chId = args[1];
const msgId = args[2];

const messaggioNuovo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#c95f34')
    .setDescription(`${nuovoMsg}`);

const msgc = message.guild.channels.cache.get(chId).messages.cache.get(msgId);
msgc.edit(messaggioNuovo);
```

In a Discord text channel I sent :

```
njb!embede 709683421210869842 709711387324317746 Prova della modifica
```

Console Error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\NNJPBot\commands\embede.js:32:8)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\NNJPBot\index.js:81:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\NNJPBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\NNJPBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\NNJPBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\NNJPBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\NNJPBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\NNJPBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Info : 
njb! : Prefix

embede : Command

Comment: I can't see where `message.guild.channels.cache.get(...).messages.cache.fetch` is being called. Could you please show the code that caused the error (at `embede.js:30:70`)?

Comment: Sorry, wrong code and error. Now I've fixed it. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is the message cache does not have the message with `msgId`. By default, Discord.js caches up to 200 messages per channel, so most likely the message with `msgId` has been removed from the cache.

You would need to fetch the message:

```js
// With await (requires it to be in an async function)
const msgc = await message.guild.channels.cache.get(chId).messages.fetch(msgId)
msgc.edit(messaggioNuovo)

// With then
message.guild.channels.cache.get(chId).messages.fetch(msgId).then(msgc =>
  msgc.edit(messaggioNuovo)
)
```